# Multi dimensional arrays in Python of a dynamic size

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

very new to python so attempting to wrap my head around multi dimensional arrays. I read the existing posts and most of them deal with multi dimensional arrays given dimensions. In my case, I do not have dimensions for the total number of rows possible. A file is being processed, which is CSV and has 7 columns, but each line, depending on meeting or failing a criteria is accordingly drafted into an array. Essentially each line has 7 columns, but the number of rows cannot be predicted. The line is being treated as a list.

My aim is to create a multidimensional array of eligible lines and then be able to access values in the array. how can I do this?

essentially, how do I tackle creating a 2D list:

```
list_2d = [[foo for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
```

The above creates an mxn sized list but in my case, I know only n (columns) and not m(rows)

Comment: umm,..say I want to create 2-d lists, with each member being accessible by specifying column and row, now given the size..I can do
list_2d = [[foo for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]

But I only know the total number of columns in my 2d array will be n, the total number of rows is dynamic and coule ba nythng, how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nest lists in lists you don't need to predefine the length of a list to use it and you can append on to it. Want another dimension simply append another list to the inner most list.

```
[[[a1, a2, a3]  , [b1, b2, b3] , [c1, c2, c3]],
[[d1, d2, d3]  , [e1, e2, e3] , [f1, f2, f3]]]
```

and to use them easily just look at [Nested List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

Comment: that looks like a list of lists...how can you access a specific index with that?

Comment: say I want to get value e2 only, then what index am I looking at?

Comment: list[1][1][1] for anyone unwilling to click on the proof of concept.

Comment: @VornoiPotato I clicked on it....now I am trying to read up on how to iterate through a 2d array in python...thanks for your help

Comment: Look up lists not arrays, lists are the thing you're looking to use here. Arrays are something else entirely. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15291/discussion-between-user1020069-and-voronoipotato)

Answer (score 3):

In python there is no need to declare list size on forehand.

an example of reading lines to a file could be this:

```
file_name = "/path/to/file"
list = []

with open(file_name) as file:
  file.readline
  if criteria:
    list.append(line)
```

For multidimensional lists. create the inner lists in a function on and return it to the append line. like so:

```
def returns_list(line):
  multi_dim_list = []
  #do stuff
  return multi_dim_list
```

exchange the last row in the first code with

```
list.append(returns_list(line))
```

Comment: here are other avilable methods http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I would be careful not to use the term `array` here (even though the OP did).  The term array is misleading as there is an `array` module and that is the common name of a `numpy.ndarray` which is much more likely to show up when googling `python array`.

Comment: I have swapped now thanks for the reminder. I use 3-4 languages daily its hard to keep them apart some times.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered this to create a simple 2D array list that is 8 elements wide and dynamic in the other dimension

```
list2d=[[] for i in xrange(8)]
```

Then you can assign any number of variables to the 8 wide array

```
list2d[0]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
list2d[1]=[12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

and so on.....

Answer (score 2):

You can even try this it worked for me

`s = [[] for y in range(n)]`

Answer (score 2):

try below

```
#beg 

a=[[]]

r=int(input("how many rows "))
c=int(input("how many cols "))

for i in range(r-1):
    a.append([])

for i in range(r):
    print("Enter elements for row ",i+1)
    for j in range(c):
        num=int(input("Enter element "))
        a[i].append(num)

for i in range(len(a)):
     print()
     for j in range(len(a[i])):
         print(a[i][j],end="  ")
```

## end

Comment: As the question asked directs that the number of rows are unpredictable hence in your above code, we cannot get the value of `r`. Better read the file this EOF and keep appending row list to the main list of list `a`

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed 'n' columns, then you can transpose in memory.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

cols = defaultdict(list)

with open('somefile.csv') as csvin:
    for row in csv.reader(csvin):
        for colno, col in enumerate(row):
            cols[colno].append(col)
```

Still not 100% sure this is your question though...